# How to sample in the matrix according to the probability in each cell

Tags: python

I tried to code the formula in pattern recognition but I can not find proper function to do the work. The problem is that I have an binary adjacency matrix `A (M*N)` and want to assign value `1` or `0` to each cell. Every cell has fixed probability `P` to be `1` and zero otherwise. I search method about sampling in python and it seems that the most methods only support sample several elements in list without considering probability. I really need help about this and any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Is your matrix a `nd.array` ? Show us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
A = (P > numpy.random.rand(4, 5)).astype(int)
```

Where `P` is your matrix of probabilities.

To make sure the probabilities are right you can test it using

```
P = numpy.ones((4, 5)) * 0.2
S = numpy.zeros((4, 5))

for i in range(100000):
    S += (P > numpy.random.rand(4, 5)).astype(int)

print S          # each element should be approximately 20000
print S.mean()   # the average should be approximately 20000, too
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your matrix of probabilities of adjacency as follows :

```
# Create your matrix
matrix = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 3))/10.
# Returns :
array([[ 0. ,  0.4,  0.2],
       [ 0.9,  0.7,  0.4],
       [ 0.1,  0. ,  0.5]])

# Now you can use np.where
threshold = 0.5
np.where(matrix<threshold, 0, 1) # you can set your threshold as you like. 
# Here set to 0.5

# Returns :
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: This solution has one `P = 0.5` for all cells, or am I mistaken?

Comment: The probability for each cell is given by the matrix `matrix`. Then I threshold to set to 1 or 0

Comment: No, `matrix` is your sampling, `threshold` is your `P`. Your output would be the same for same `matrix` and same `threshold` and it most probably shouldn't be.